# Getting extra data from the join table

Tags: sql, mysql

Ok so i have this structure

PRODUCTS

```
* PRODUCT_ID (primary key)
* PRODUCT_NAME
```

CATEGORIES

```
* CATEGORY_ID (primary key)
* CATEGORY_NAME
* CODE
```

PRODUCT_CATEGORIES_MAP

```
* PRODUCT_ID (primary key, foreign key to PRODUCTS)
* CATEGORY_ID (primary key, foreign key to CATEGORIES)
* QUANTITY
```

I am using this query

```
SELECT * FROM `products`
where id in (
    SELECT `product_id`
    FROM `categorizations`
    WHERE category_id = (
        SELECT id
        FROM `categories`
        where code = 'something'))
```

this works great but i am just getting a list of products. I need the quantity of each one one in the join table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table names in your explanation are different from your sample query. I used the ones from your query.

```
SELECT p.product_id  ,
       p.product_name,
       pc.quantity
FROM   `products` p
       JOIN `categorizations` pc
       ON     p.id = pc.`product_id`
       JOIN `categories` c
       ON     c.id = pc.category_id
WHERE  c.code      = 'something'
```

Comment: +1 that is what I would use too, except I would use LEFT JOINs instead of normal JOINs, so the query would return even products that are not assigned to a category, for example.

Comment: @Freek - That isn't the semantics of the OP's original query though. The purpose seems to be to only bring back products matching category code `something`

Comment: Ah, you are correct ! If a product is not assigned to a category, it wouldn't have a category code to be matched in the first place. Screwing up - one of the "perks" of working late :)

Answer (score 2):

sql's a bit rusty but here goes

select PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME, QUANTITY
from PRODUCTS as A, PRODUCTS_CATEGORIES_MAP as B, CATEGORIES as C
where A.PRODUCT_ID  = B.PRODUCT_ID
and C.CATEGORY_ID = B.CATEGORY_ID
and C.CODE = 'something'

Answer (score 1):

You may want to sum over quantity in case product is in more categories.

```
select p.*, 
       sum(m.quantity) quantity
  from products p
  join categorizations m on m.product_id = p.product_id
  join categories on c.category_id = m.category_id 
   and c.code = 'something'
 group by p.product_id
```

Otherwise look at @Martin code

Answer (score 0):

The detail that you want is the quantity of the product and so, why not start by them....you can always retrieve the products because you have the product_id.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT `product_id`, `quantity`
    FROM `categorizations`
    WHERE category_id = (
        SELECT id
        FROM `categories`
        where code = 'something'))) AS `filtered_categorization`
LEFT JOIN `products`
    ON (`products`.`id` == `filtered_categorization`.`product`);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
select
 p.*,
 c.category_id,
 c.category_name,
 pcm.quantity
from
 products p
inner join product_categories_map pcm on p.product_id = pcm.product_id
inner join categories c on pcm.category_id = c.category_id
where
 c.code = 'something'
order by
 p.product_id, c.category_id;
```